# New dual citizen Canada/Australia

Tags: australian-citizens, canadian-citizens

I am a Australian citizen by birth living in Canada. I recently got my canadian citizenship and also got married. I am trying to decide whether to apply for my Canadian passport with my maiden or married name? I have travel coming up to Australia and tickets are booked under my maiden name ( i believe i can contact the airline to have it changed to my married name?). We are also planning to move back to Australia next year so trying to eliminate having to get a new canadian passport after we move by getting it in my married name first time. Any advice would be appreciate.

TIA!

Comment: If your Australian passport is still in your maiden name then just show that to the airline.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely suggest getting your new Canadian passport in your married name. The fact that your tickets are booked in your maiden name should not be a problem, since you still have a valid Australian passport.

To avoid any possible problems, bring a copy of your marriage certificate to your flight checkin. Also, call your airline ahead of time if you want reassurance that this won't be a problem for them.

Comment: Do you think it will be issue having the 2 passports under different names? Or should be fine if I have our marriage license?

Comment: It should be fine if you have your marriage license. Airlines understand that people get married all the time, and they understand Western family name conventions very well. As a new dual passport holder, you may find the following question useful too: [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel)

Comment: Just an observation: marriage licences and marriage certificates are two different things (at least, in some parts of the world). You need your marriage certificate.

Comment: Just a question: if tickets are booked under the OP’s maiden name, and her Australian passport allows her entry to Canada, why would it be necessary to bring the marriage certificate? To show to whom? The airline? How would they know about the marriage/change of name/citizenship unless the OP tells them? Or Immigration? If the latter, wouldn’t it be better to carry evidence of getting her Canadian citizenship (certificate, letter etc - I’m not sure what it would be).

Comment: @Traveller: If the return tickets are already booked, then there probably won't be a need to show the marriage certificate or Canadian passport at all. However, it's a good idea to have it available just in case, for example if she loses her Australian passport. There is a certificate for acquisition of Canadian citizenship, but nobody needs to see that after getting a Canadian passport (the passport is sufficient for all travel purposes).

Comment: Canadian citizens now need a Canadian passport to enter the country. So I will have to show my Canadian passport when checking in to come back. That’s the only time I would be concerned about my ticket and passport being different.

Comment: Yup. That won't be a problem. You can show the airline both passports, they see that sort of thing all the time (source: I have two passports).